# Why do coefficients of standard quadratic equation affect the shape of quadratic graph?

Tags: quadratics

The standard equation is ax^2 + bx + c. While I was plotting the graph on Desmos, an increase in the value of 'a' would cause the graph to be narrow, and a decrease would cause it to be broad. As for 'b', it would cause the graph to shift sideways/horizontally; for 'c', it would shift the graph vertically.

b: an increase in the value would cause it to shift towards the left except when a<0
c: an increase in the value would cause it to move upwards.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! I will edit this.

Comment: "b: an increase in the value would cause it to shift towards the left" Not necessarily, try this when $ a<0$.

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: The effects of the three parameters are illustrated nicely in [How does the middle term of a quadratic $ax^2 + bx + c$ influence the graph of $y = x^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2932621/139123) There are many other relevant questions and answers, such as [Why does the width of the graph of a parabola depend only on $a$, not $b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1723597/139123)

Answer (score 0):

When we complete the square, we get a(x+(b/2a)^2) + (4ac-b^2)/4a. Changing a changes the width of the parabola because lower a means that the inputs far away from -b/2a have lower outputs, whereas higher a means that the inputs far away from -b/2a have higher outputs.

The vertex of the parabola has coordinates (-b/2a, (4ac-b^2)/4a). Varying b chooses a vertex from -ax^2+c as seen in [Why do the vertices of $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, when fixing $a$ and $c$ but varying $b$, lie on $g(x) = -ax^2 + c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4233833/why-do-the-vertices-of-fx-ax2-bx-c-when-fixing-a-and-c-but-varyi?rq=1) Varying c simply shifts the graph up or down.